# Sign in with Google, identification.

Tags: java, php, android, oauth

I have an android application - service, which sends data to the server and user is identified by email and password.

As I see I could save Google ID, name, email and etc once user is logged in, but if I use just Google ID to identify user in my service that could be unsafe. right? My service use POST method to send data to the server.

So, my question - is there any way to save Google account information and use it to identify that user on my server safely?

Comment: What are you using the information for? API calls?

Comment: I send GPS coordinates to the server, I want to integrate Google sign up. I think I would use $user = $oauth2->userinfo->get();   $user['id'] - for user identification. This ID is unique and it is not going to change in the future. But I have doubts about safety, somebody else could use this ID to send GPS data to the server. I think it is easy to get it.